# Are political endorsements even remotely acceptable?

Tags: support, profile-page

I just saw someone's profile blatantly endorse a political candidate.  Is this even remotely acceptable?  This is site's content.  The site explicitly does not wish to be a social network.  We are not talking about endorsement of a political position or a political point of view, or even a party.

It's an endorsement of a specific candidate.  It's done anonymously.  This site has no validation that its users are US-based.  But the endorsement was of a candidate for President in the US.  Without such validation, this maybe viewed as a direct interference in the US elections by the site itself.

Comment: Frankly if you want real attention to this, post on https://meta.stackexchange.com. The real SE rules geeks hang out over there. I don't know what rules really are for profiles, but there seem to be some; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339235/is-stack-exchange-staff-removing-gofundme-links for example. Or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/why-is-the-f-word-still-allowed-in-profiles

Comment: As you might have noticed, your question here is the first with profile-page tag... [Unlike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profile-page) over there...

Comment: I can guarantee I wouldn’t be writing questions like [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43916/24826) if I were a Russian interferer.

Comment: Actually, because you're being so aggressive over it, I'm considering adding an endorsement myself as a non-US national (Belgium)

Comment: @Stormblessed Leaving aside that I am a US citizen... even if I weren't, the answer would be still the same. it's illegal for foreigners to benefit a specific candidate.  it's not illegal to do issue advocacy.  Oh, and I am not a foreigner.  There's been a number of questions about this on politics.SE.  You may want to look through their answers.

Comment: @Stormblessed there is nothing specific about Russia.  It's illegal for non-citizens provide material support to a campaign of a any candidate.  It doesn't matter of if the foreigner is Russian or Canadian.  As long as they don't have a US citizenship or a Green Card, they can't provide this type of support to a politician's campaign.

Comment: @Nzall I would consult with a lawyer before doing that.  A number of foreign nationals have been indicted for their actions in attempts to advocate for Trump 2016.

Comment: @Nzall  BTW, personally, I think it's over the top for someone from Belgium telling Americans who they should vote for.

Comment: @grovkin why? [You said yourself that](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/47312/18862) *"it's not unusual for US-based political advisers to advise and even run campaigns of foreign leaders. For example, James Carville, who got Bill Clinton elected, also ran Ehud Barak's 1999 campaign against Netanyahu."* So it's okay for Americans to weigh in on foreign elections but it's not okay the other way around? I'd say that as long as they aren't paid endorsements, they're volunteering and it's just a person expressing their opinion.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica  I didn't say I liked it.  I just said it's not new.  I was answering the question which was posited.  The question was whether there was precedent for US Presidents' to involvement in foreign elections directly.  And I pointed to a previous occasion when it, by all accounts, happened.  As to whether there is symmetry... well, that's not how the law works.  If it's against the law, it's illegal....  it doesn't matter that it's legal for the US to do it to other countries. If no law forbids, it's not illegal.  This isn't a moral judgement (good vs bad). It's a fact.

Comment: @grovkin but isn't it upon you making the accusation to argue it actually breaks the law? You don't seem sure whereas others, including myself, are fairly sure it isn't, and certainly not at the level of Russian trolls who successfully deepened divisions already present in American society.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica no.  it just doesn't work that way.  And I am saying this as someone who actually had to call the police on certain issues.  You report facts.  You can say that you think it's illegal, but you are not arguing the law when you call the police (unless you are a lawyer filling out a police report as a complainant or on behalf of a complainant).  You can suggest to them that it is illegal, but usually that only works if you are trying to argue that they should investigate out of abundance of caution.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're conflating the [Russian social media campaigns of 2016](https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/10/russian-facebook-ads-house-intelligence-full-list/) with general speech. In the case of those ads

1. The ads were not meant as political discourse
2. They were deliberately inflammatory

In this case we have something different. A user has put a political endorsement in their profile

1. That is **the political speech of that user**
2. Unprovable to be part of a **sustained foreign campaign**

Trying to police such a rule about political endorsements in user profiles is impossible anyway. If the user is using Tor or a VPN, there's no way to prove which country they are from. Furthermore, user profile pages are infrequently visited.

Comment: It's a particular type of political ad.  This type of ad is called a "testimonial."  They are very common and not unique to politics.  We have no idea what the actual person(s) behind the ad think.  The way to police such ads (if the site wants to police them) is to make them against site's rules to put all political ads in profiles.  I don't know if it's currently against the rules or not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about SE rules, but your suggestion that this is illegal seems to be wrong; see in particular the 3rd & 4th para from this [*Law & Crime* 2018 article](https://lawandcrime.com/politics/aba-legal-fact-check-when-is-it-illegal-for-foreign-nationals-to-influence-u-s-elections/), penned by the American Bar Association Legal Fact Check team, based on an actual US court decision:

> Congress has wrestled with questions of foreign interference with the U.S. electoral process for many years, including following the 1996 elections when the majority-Republican Senate organized hearings on Chinese influence in Bill Clinton’s reelection. The First Amendment allows some protection for foreign nationals to influence public opinion, but federal election law clearly prohibits political contributions to candidates by foreign nationals as well as candidates’ acceptance of anything of value from foreign nationals.
>
> Six years ago, the U.S. Supreme Court upheld a decision by a U.S. District Court in Washington, D.C., that Congress can ban individuals who lawfully reside in the U.S. and are neither U.S. citizens nor “permanent residents” from making donations or gifts related to any election. In that case, Bluman v. Federal Election Commission, a three-judge panel said the limitation was a legitimate tool for government to prevent “foreign influence over U.S. elections.” The decision specifically banned contributions to candidates and political parties as well as “express-advocacy” expenditures — those ads that clearly support or oppose a specific electoral outcome. The Supreme Court affirmed the decision without comment.
>
> But the lower court said the ban “does not restrain foreign nationals from speaking out about issues or spending money to advocate their views about issues.” As an example, the FEC said foreign nationals can underwrite the broadcast of apolitical ads aimed at exposing the alleged political bias of the media. And this past summer, a pro-Saudi group purchased a series of anti-Qatar ads clearly intended to influence U.S. political opinion.
>
> [...]  The FEC has also determined that individuals, including foreign nationals, may volunteer personal services to a federal candidate or federal political committee without making a contribution.

I've also alerted the Stack Exchange staff through their [contact page](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to this thread. They may want to run this by their own lawyers and perhaps post a response.

Comment: Can you, please, point out where I made the statement that this is "outright illegal"?  BTW, the profile in question was a straight-out testimonial-style ad for Warren (for President).  The profile has changed since then to exclude the Warren-endorsement part.

Comment: @grovkin: You've implied it with your second para "maybe viewed as a direct interference in the US elections by the site itself" and subsequent comments such as "it's illegal for foreigners to benefit a specific candidate". You have also repeated the word "illegal" like seven times in your comments on this page.

Comment: @grovkin: okay, so you're actually arguing it's a grey area, so SE should ban the practice to be on the safe side?

Comment: I was asking if SE does ban it in order to be on the safe side or if it is willing to take the risk.  I just wanted to know where SE stands.

Comment: Okay, so contacting SE directly would have been the best course in that case. I've actually done that for your now. (To be totally safe they could just close down politics SE.)

Comment: @grovkin: interestingly, running a site like politics SE seems bound to alienate some users, which seems contrary to some other goals, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298130/3588161

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should be removed it, it's probably in compliance with the law, and there are many endorsements on the internet. To entertain your interpretation of the law is above our paygrade, so to speak, which is why I'd suggest bothering them with this (in my view ridiculous) proposal.

I should make it clear, based on comments, that I don't wish for the FBI to act against one of our users, but I don't think it's inappropriate for another user to inquire with law enforcement if something is against the law, ridiculous as I might find the suggestion.

---

If you think users here or the company is in violation of US law, it may be easier to contact the relevant US law enforcement agencies. Since you've asked about this before, may I remind you of the following [answer by Fizz](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/46522/18862) detailing how to do that (partial quote of that answer):

> As you found out, the FBI has a Foreign Influence Task Force. I'm not really familiar with it. Its [description page](https://www.fbi.gov/investigate/counterintelligence/foreign-influence) says of its goals:
>
> > Through the FITF, the FBI is taking a three-pronged approach to this serious threat:
> >
> > - Investigations and operations: The FITF works with FBI field offices across the country to counter the extensive influence operations of our foreign adversaries.
> > - Information and intelligence sharing: The FBI works closely with other intelligence community agencies, as well as with state and local law enforcement partners and election officials, to ensure a common understanding of the threat and a unified strategy to address it.
> > - Private sector partnerships: The FBI considers strategic engagement with U.S. technology companies, including threat indicator sharing, to be important in combating foreign influence actors.
>
> On a subpage they give this contact info:
>
> > State and local election officials or campaign staff should report suspicious activity to their local FBI field office and also notify FBI CyWatch at cywatch@fbi.gov or 1-855-292-3937.

If you're serious about your inquiry then I suggest exploring the contact options at the end of the quote. After all, if you think there's a crime going on, it may be better to leave it to the professionals.

And as they say, the FBI is already engaged in private sector partnership, so if you suspect something fishy is going on, I really think the Bureau should be informed.

It's no coincidence [the Department of Homeland Security has the following motto](https://www.dhs.gov/see-something-say-something):

> If you **see** something, **say** something®

Comment: I would first like to know if this acceptable use, from the company's perspective, or an oversight.  I am not about to report it to the FBI or FEC if the company views it as rogue users going outside of the limits.  I am pretty sure I made my question clear.  Is this something the company allows and considers par for the course.  Or is it an aberrant behavior.

Comment: @grovkin also, you may need to specify exactly which instance of support of a candidate you're referring to. I think we've had a user here for a while whose nickname was something related to Senator Bernie Sanders, who is running for president again. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: I was wondering about stormblessed's [profile](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/24826/stormblessed).  Seems like a blatant ad for Warren.

Comment: @grovkin I'm fairly confident at this point that Warren will not be the Democratic candidate for president. Does that alleviate your concerns?

Comment: I don't make the laws.

Comment: @grovkin Senators do, if bills come to the floor. ;)

Comment: Levity aside, you do see that if this person is not a US-person, this is interference, right?

Comment: @grovkin I am not trained in the law, nor am I a US citizen, but I don't think this is a violation of US law. From [fec.gov](https://www.fec.gov/updates/foreign-nationals/): *"Generally, an individual (including a foreign national) may volunteer personal services to a federal candidate or federal political committee without making a contribution. The Act provides this volunteer "exemption" as long as the individual performing the service is not compensated by anyone."*

Comment: Which is why it is relevant that this site is not a social-network site.  A political advertisement placed in the space which should be taken by personal information is not just volunteering.  Generally volunteers have to certify that they are not paid by anyone to perform their volunteer services.  This prevents 3rd parties from donating excessive amounts by hiring "volunteers."

Comment: @grovkin well now you're getting into legal territory that most here will not be trained to handle. I can cite the example of a foreign artist giving a free concert for a campaign and it wasn't ruled a violation of the Act (see the previous link). Given that, it's much easier just to contact relevant people at the FBI or the DOJ. Even if it's a violation technically, they may deem it too insignificant to act on. I'd say, do something you like and don't worry about it too much. This profile bio isn't going to sway Democrats. ;)

Comment: It's not about being persuasive.  Interference is currently being treated as a form of trespassing: it is unwelcome and guarded-against even if it is inconsequential.

Comment: @grovkin well I hope you get a response from SE headquarters. Note that it's late Friday / early Saturday now so [at best you're getting a poorly thought out response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334370/387405). You may get some response during the week, but it could also take [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/387405). By SE's definition, the election may have taken place by then. Anyway, if you do contact the FBI and they do respond, I hope you post their reply as an answer here. I'm interested in their take on things.

Comment: Ok so now you’re telling the user to call the FBI? Ok I’m removing it. Wtf

Comment: There’s a prominent user who has said they’re a “major MAGA supporter” on Sci-fi (and other accounts) for at least 9 months or so—that’s not apparently been a problem.

Comment: If this kind of suggestion is acceptable, I don’t feel welcome to be on this site.

Comment: @Stormblessed I think you're making too much of my answer. I'm saying that if people think there's a violation of election law, then they can take it up with the relevant authorities. It's a way of saying *this is really above our paygrade, go bother them with this (ridiculous) proposal*. I don't think you should have removed it, it's fine, there are tons of endorsements on the internet.

Comment: @Stormblessed I've elaborated a bit. Again, I didn't mean to make you feel unwelcome. And I made the suggestion to call the FBI for the reason of *inquiry*. I knew I wasn't going to convince the asker that they're chasing something that's not worth anyone's time chasing, but the specific unit of the FBI tasked with foreign influence may be better positioned to explain what they really do, which probably doesn't include private citizens putting a few lines of endorsements in their profile online.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica oh, then I misunderstood.  I don't think calling FBI for legal advice is what FBI is for.  FBI's mission does not include providing legal advice.  They exist for the purpose of investigating violations of the Federal law.  If a person is not sure about legality of their own actions, or their potential actions, they are expected to consult their own lawyer.

Comment: @Stormblessed please, do understand that this isn't a suggestion that what you did was unethical.  I was simply pointing out that this type of thing may be treated as illegal in the current climate.  While I do not welcome non-US persons telling me for whom or why I should vote, I don't think it should be illegal to simply talk.  However, given the current legal climate and the fact that we ALL can become subjects of suspicion, as users of this site, I did want the site to clarify if this is outside of the bounds of acceptable use.

Comment: @grovkin if you think a crime has been committed, do you call the police or do you call you own lawyer to make sure it's actually a crime? On the one hand you argue *"this is outside of the bounds of acceptable use"* but on the other hand you say *"I don't think calling FBI for legal advice is what FBI is for"*. I don't think you can have it both ways. On the one hand you think it's a problem and on the other hand you're not willing to report it. If you don't think it's serious enough of a violation to bother the FBI with, why would it be serious enough for the company to respond?

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica you don't call the police to "make sure it's a crime."  You call the police to report what you think is a crime.  And they may tell you that it's not and they won't investigate it.  But you can't call for advice.  The company should respond to make it clear to its users whether continued involvement with the company risks violating the US election law or whether the company errs on the side of caution (at the expense of reducing the services available to its users).

Comment: @grovkin the company should do a lot of things but they don't seem beholden to the moral standards you and I may have. The company has already stopped responding on the main meta site and they're [moving to a model where users can provide feedback anonymously only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339059/387405).

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica this isn't about morals.  this is about legal protections both of its users and, frankly, of its employees as well.  the company is a business -- not a religion.

Comment: @grovkin I'm not sure why you're directing that at me. You really should convince the company of that, I hold no power over them. ;)

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica I am directing it at you because you are the one who suggested that this is an issue of morals (in your previous comment when you said "the company should do a lot of things but they don't seem beholden to the *moral standards* you and I may have").  And I am pointing out that this isn't a question of morals.

Comment: @grovkin some might argue that respecting the law is a moral position. I'm not sure the company would agree with that position. They may well hold the view that whatever they can get away with is fine by them. Indeed, a fellow user and former moderator is [taking the company to court over slanderous claims by the company](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users). That's not a company I'd expect to be too bothered about US election law. At worst they may face a fine, that doesn't seem to have bothered them in the past.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica to nitpick... if they are actually found guilty of something... *anything* really, then a fine would be the least harsh punishment they can face rather than the most harsh punishment they can face.

Comment: @grovkin I don't think so. Most of these issues merely result in a fine. For example a suit describing *"a shocking pattern of illegality involving the Trump Foundation – including unlawful coordination with the Trump presidential campaign, repeated and willful self-dealing, and much more,"* [resulted only in a monetary fine](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/nov/07/donald-trump-charity-foundation-misuse-lawsuit). You'd have to be quite bold to go to jail over campaign finance. Trump's lawyer did, but in the context of many other charges (mostly tax evasion).

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica didn't Trump's lawyer plead guilty to some crimes?  That seems like more than just a fine.  Regardless of that, there is zero chance that SE lawyers are as good as Trump's lawyers.  So I doubt they have been as careful as Trump has been in staying within the law.  But I would like to know where SE stands before making up my own opinion on the topic.

Comment: @grovkin yes he pleaded guilty, according to Wikipedia *"The investigation led him to plead guilty on August 21, 2018, to eight counts including campaign finance violations, tax fraud, and bank fraud. Cohen said he violated campaign finance laws at the direction of Trump and "for the principal purpose of influencing" the 2016 presidential election."* I think there are also instances of FARA violations leading to jail time, but those are mostly accompanied by other charges (making false statements, tax evasion, conspiracy charges, etc.).